# php static variable initialization doesn't make sense here

Tags: php, codeigniter, static

I am talking about `Common.php` file of CodeIgniter framework(system/core folder).

// not required to answer the question though!

I have been going through the code and couldn't make sense of these particular lines at **start** of `load_class` function.

```
static $_classes = array();

// Does the class exist?  If so, we're done...
if (isset($_classes[$class]))
{
    return $_classes[$class];
```

My doubt specifically is, isn't it pointless to declare a variable to an empty array, and immediately check if some key exists in that array? or am I missing something related to `static` keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` modifier in front of that variable means that the value of `$_classes` persists after each function call.

So the first time that function is called, `$_classes` does not yet exist so it gets created as an empty array.

Since its empty, the class doesn't exist, so it gets loaded and put in the `$_classes` variable.

Now when the function terminates, because it is `static`, it does not get cleaned up, and its value persists.

The next time the function is called, PHP knows it already exists so it is *not* initialized as an empty array, it still contains what it had the last time the function was called.

See [using static variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) for more information.

Comment: I haven't ever used `static` in php! I guess there is **lot** of _php_ to master. Thank you.